# SQL Server choosing inefficient execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, query-performance

I've got a query that gets run in certain circumstances with an 'over-simplified' execution plan that actually turns out to be quite slow (3-5 seconds). The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Salesperson.*
FROM Salesperson
    INNER JOIN SalesOrder on Salesperson.Id = SalesOrder.SalespersonId
    INNER JOIN PrelimOrder on SalesOrder.Id = PrelimOrder.OrderId
    INNER JOIN PrelimOrderStatus on PrelimOrder.CurrentStatusId = PrelimOrderStatus.Id
    INNER JOIN PrelimOrderStatusType on PrelimOrderStatus.StatusTypeId = PrelimOrderStatusType.Id
WHERE 
    PrelimOrderStatusType.StatusTypeCode = 'Draft'
    AND Salesperson.EndDate IS NULL
```

and the slow execution plan looks like:

[image: Slow Execution Plan]

The thing that stands out straight away is that the actual number of rows/executions is significantly higher than the respective estimates:

[image: IX_SalesOrder_SalespersonId]

[image: UX_PrelimOrder_OrderId]

[image: UX_PrelimOrderStatus_Id]

If I remove the `Salesperson.EndDate IS NULL` clause, then a faster, parallelized execution plan is run:

[image: Fast Execution Plan]

A similar execution plan also runs quite fast if I remove the DISTINCT keyword.

From what I can gather, it seems that the optimiser decides, based on its incorrect estimates, that the query won't be costly to run and therefore doesn't choose the parallelized plan. But I can't for the life of me figure out why it is choosing the incorrect plan. I have checked my statistics and they are all as they should be. I have tested in both SQL Server 2008 to 2016 with identical results.

Comment: @BrockAdams Totally forgot about those, sorry about that ^_^ thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT` is expensive.  So, it is best to avoid it.  Something like this:

```
SELECT sp.*
FROM Salesperson sp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SalesOrder so INNER JOIN
                   PrelimOrder po 
                   ON so.Id = po.OrderId INNER JOIN
                   PrelimOrderStatus pos
                   ON po.CurrentStatusId = pos.Id INNER JOIN
                   PrelimOrderStatusType post
                   ON pos.StatusTypeId = post.Id
              WHERE sp.Id = so.SalespersonId AND
                    post.StatusTypeCode = 'Draft'
             ) AND
      sp.EndDate IS NULL;
```

Note: An index on `SalesPerson(EndDate, Id)` would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately that query results in the same slow execution plan as my initial query.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff already said, `DISTINCT` usually is bad news for performance. Often it means you're amassing way too much data and then squeezing it back together in a more compact set. Better to keep it small all throughout the process, if possible.

Also, it's kind of counter-intuitive that the query plan with index scans turns out to be faster than the one with index seeks; it seems (in this case) parallelism makes up for it. You could try playing around with the 
[Cost Threshold For Parallelism Option](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188603(v=sql.105).aspx) but beware that this is a server-wide setting! (then again, in my opinion the default of 5 is rather high for most use-cases I've run into personally; CPU's are aplenty these days, time still isn't =).

Bit of a long reach, but I was wondering if you could 'split' the query in 2, thus eliminating (a small) part of the guesswork of the server. I'm assuming here that `StatusTypeCode` is unique. (verify the datatype of the variable too!)

```
DECLARE @StatusTypeId int

SELECT @StatusTypeId = Id 
  FROM PrelimOrderStatusType 
 WHERE StatusTypeCode = 'Draft'

SELECT Salesperson.*
  FROM Salesperson
 WHERE Salesperson.EndDate IS NULL
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                  FROM SalesOrder 
                    ON SalesOrder.SalespersonId = Salesperson.Id
                  JOIN PrelimOrder 
                    ON PrelimOrder.OrderId = SalesOrder.Id 
                  JOIN PrelimOrderStatus 
                    ON PrelimOrderStatus.Id = PrelimOrder.CurrentStatusId
                   AND PrelimOrderStatus.StatusTypeId = @StatusTypeId)
```

If it doesn't help, could you give give the definition of the indexes that are being used?

Comment: I've tested that query using EXISTS instead of DISTINCT, but it results a similar query plan with still the same discrepancies in the execution plan. There is a speed improvement, but that comes about as a result of removing the join on PrelimOrderStatusType. I've tried setting my cost threshold to 1 previously, but that had no effect in this case.